# Passing PHP Session from Page 1 to Page 2

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have at the top of my Page1.php the following.

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ALL_YEAR'] = $_POST['ALL_YEAR'];
?>
```

I am trying to capture the form selection for a select called ALL_YEAR when this button is pushed:

```
<button type="button" value="Send" id="avgSubmitXLEW_1_12_3" onClick="location.href=this.value">Configure</button>
```

on Page2.php I have this at the top:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    $home = $_REQUEST['ALL_YEAR'];
?>
```

Farther down in the body of the page I have this:

```php
<? echo $_session['home'];?>
```

The value is not showing up in the echo?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always use `<?php` instead of `<?` at the beginning of your code. Not all server has the short tag enabled.

Comment: Just FYI, $_session isn't the same thing as $_SESSION. The case is important.

Comment: Also, you are using $_REQUEST which is a super-global and can raise some security concerns. While your code may not be affected for its current purpose, its always a better idea to just avoid it.

Comment: The only potential problem with $_REQUEST is if the server enables inclusion of cookies in this variable, which is not by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of :

```
$home = $_REQUEST['ALL_YEAR'];
...
<? echo $_session['home']; ?>
```

you should do :

```
$home = $_SESSION['ALL_YEAR'];
...
<?php echo $home; ?>
```

Comment: Always use `<?php` instead of `<?` at the beginning of your code. Not all server has the short tag enabled.

Answer (score 0):

PHP variable names are case sensitive:

```
 <? echo $_session['home'];?>
```

should be

```
 <? echo $_SESSION['home'];?>
```

Comment: There is no key is the `SESSION` called `home`

Comment: it's irrelevant what the key in the session is if you're not accessing the actual SESSION...